# Ignoring exception from a finished function in Google Cloud Console Test

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-console

I am trying to email myself OnCreate of my firebase database.  I am receiving the error "Ignoring exception from a finished function" when testing this in google cloud functions.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
   user: gmailEmail,
   pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

const APP_NAME = 'Your App';
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.database.ref('/PickupRequests{pushID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  return sendWelcomeEmail();
});

async function sendWelcomeEmail() {
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "<noreply@firebase.com>",
    to: "info@abc.com",
    subject: "New Request"
  };
  await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
  return console.log("Success!");
}
```

I expect to receive an email but instead I am receiving the error from Google Cloud tester that states "Ignoring exception from a finished function" despite the fact that the console is also returning "Success!".  Here is the complete error:

> ```
>  "textPayload": "Ignoring exception from a finished function",
>   "insertId": "000000-5e081b31-9b2f-4f9a-a6a6-6c7ca4d38814",
>   "resource": {
>     "type": "cloud_function",
>     "labels": {
>       "project_id": "your-app",
>       "region": "us-central1",
>       "function_name": "sendWelcomeEmail"
>     }
>   },
>   "timestamp": "2019-05-31T00:56:56.926Z",
>   "severity": "DEBUG",
>   "labels": {
>     "execution_id": "jbvvfsrrf8yz"
>   },
>   "logName": "projects/your-app/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
>   "trace": "projects/your-app/traces/5af3a317b80ee34154c1caf1536fc16e",
>   "receiveTimestamp": "2019-05-31T00:57:02.981796854Z"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by the following code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const username = functions.config().gmail.email;
const password = functions.config().gmail.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
   user: gmailEmail,
   pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});
exports.sendPickupRequest = functions.database.ref('/PickupRequests/{pushId}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {

  const val = snapshot.val();
  const final = JSON.stringify(val)
  const mailOptions = {
    from: gmailEmail,
    to: "info@abc.com",
    subject: "New Request"
  };
  try {
    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('email sent');
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error while sending the email:', error);
  }
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Please explain what's real problem?